# How to skip key error in pandas?

Tags: pandas, key

I have a dictionary and a list. For each key in the list, I want to plot the associated values with that key.

I have the following code in pandas:

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(22)
import seaborn as sns; sns.set(color_codes=True)

window = int(math.ceil(5000.0 / 100))
xticks = range(-2500,2500,window)

sns.tsplot([mydictionary[k] for k in mylist],time=xticks,color="g")

plt.legend(['blue'])
```

However, I get KeyError: xxxx

I can manually remove all problematic keys in my list, but that will take a long time. Is there a way I can skip this key error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are looking for a way to just swallow the key error, use a `try` & `except`. However, cleaning up the data in advance would be much more elegant.

**Example:**

```
mydictionary = {
    'a': 1,
    'b': 2,
    'c': 3,
}

mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

result = []
for k in mylist:
    try:
        result.append(mydictionary[k])
    except KeyError:
        pass

print(result)

>>> [1, 2, 3]
```

You will need to construct the list prior to using it in your seaborn plot. Afterwards, pass the list with the call:
`sns.tsplot(result ,time=xticks,color="g")`